# Dynamic Groups of Fields and Values for Display

Tags: html, css

We have an web application that is 100% derived from a database and WebServices combined.  The database references the labels and what field names are used in the WebServices to show values.   Basically, at the end HTML output, I have no idea what will be displayed or how many groups and fields will be displayed on the page.

This is my [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gavinlandon/wpzcdq0d/)

```
.group {
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

The client wants the groups that are stacked on top of each other, group 3, in the above example, should be closer to group 1 and not have so much space between them.  In fact, they want the same space as when you shrink the window or running on a Mobile, to have 20px between the groups on all sides, period. Float: Left, which is what I'm using, aligns the top with the bottom of the tallest group from the previous row, which isn't what the client wants.  Is there a way to do this with PURE CSS or will I have to use Angular or some other Javascript Library.   I prefer to use pure CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my own problem.   I've updated my 
[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gavinlandon/wpzcdq0d/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 740px)
{
  .groupcol {
    width: auto!important;
    float: none!important;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 0px!important;
    margin-bottom: -10px!important;
  }
  .float {
    float: none!important;
    width: auto!important;
    margin-bottom: 20px!important;
  }
}

.table {
  display: table;
  border: 0px solid red;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 720px;
  min-width: 361px;
  border: 0px solid blue;
}

.groupcol {
  width: 340px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.float {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.group {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 340px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #ccc;
}

.title {
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 5px
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.data {
  display: table;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #666;
}

.label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: .5px dotted #ddd;
  border-bottom: .5px solid #ddd;
}

.value {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: .5px solid #ddd;
}
```